# Why does qi::skip fail with tokens from the lexer?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

I'm using boost::spirit lex and qi to parse some source code.

I already skip white spaces from the input string using the lexer. What I would like to do is to switch skipping the comments depending on the context in the parser.

Here is a basic demo. See the comments in Grammar::Grammar() for my problem:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

typedef lex::lexertl::token<char const*, boost::mpl::vector<std::string>, boost::mpl::false_ > token_type;
typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type> lexer_type;

struct TokenId
{
   enum type
   {
      INVALID_TOKEN_ID = lex::min_token_id,
      COMMENT
   };
};

struct Lexer : lex::lexer<lexer_type>
{
public:
   lex::token_def<std::string> comment;
   lex::token_def<std::string> identifier;
   lex::token_def<std::string> lineFeed;
   lex::token_def<std::string> space;

   Lexer()
   {
      comment = "\\/\\*.*?\\*\\/|\\/\\/[^\\r\\n]*";
      identifier = "[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*";
      space = "[\\x20\\t\\f\\v]+";
      lineFeed = "(\\r\\n)|\\r|\\n";

      this->self = space[lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore];
      this->self += lineFeed[lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore];
      this->self.add
         (comment, TokenId::COMMENT)
         (identifier)
         (';')
         ;
   }
};

typedef Lexer::iterator_type Iterator;

void traceComment(const std::string& content)
{
   std::cout << "  comment: " << content << std::endl;
}

class Grammar : public qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
   typedef token_type skipped_t;

   qi::rule<Iterator, qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type> m_start;
   qi::rule<Iterator, qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type, skipped_t> m_variable;
   qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::unused_type> m_comment;

public:
   Lexer lx;

public:
   Grammar() :
      Grammar::base_type(m_start)
   {
// This does not work (comments are not skipped in m_variable)
      m_start = *(
            m_comment[phx::bind(&traceComment, qi::_1)]
         |  qi::skip(qi::token(TokenId::COMMENT))[m_variable]
         );

      m_variable = lx.identifier >> lx.identifier >> ';';
      m_comment = qi::token(TokenId::COMMENT);
/** But this works:
      m_start = *(
         m_comment[phx::bind(&traceComment, qi::_1)]
         | m_variable
         );

      m_variable = qi::skip(qi::token(TokenId::COMMENT))[lx.identifier >> lx.identifier >> ';'];
      m_comment = qi::token(TokenId::COMMENT);
*/
   }
};

void test(const char* code)
{
   std::cout << code << std::endl;

   Grammar parser;
   const char* begin = code;
   const char* end = code + strlen(code);
   tokenize_and_parse(begin, end, parser.lx, parser);

   if (begin == end)
      std::cout << "-- OK --" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "-- FAILED --" << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   test("/* kept */ int foo;");
   test("int /* ignored */ foo;");
   test("int foo /* ignored */;");
   test("int foo; // kept");
}
```

The output is:

```
/* kept */ int foo;
  comment: /* kept */
-- OK --

int /* ignored */ foo;
-- FAILED --

int foo /* ignored */;
-- FAILED --

int foo; // kept
  comment: // kept
-- OK --
```

Is there any issue with skipped_t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is what I would expect from my experience.

When you write

```
my_rule = qi::skip(ws) [ foo >> lit(',') >> bar >> lit('=') >> baz ];
```

this is essentially the same as writing

```
my_rule = *ws >> foo >> *ws >> lit(',') >> *ws >> bar >> *ws >> lit('=') >> *ws >> baz;
```

(assuming that `ws` is rule with no attribute. If it has an attribute in your grammar, that attribute is ignored, as if using `qi::omit`.)

Notably, the skipper does not get propogated inside of the `foo` rule. So `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` can still be whitespace-sensitive in the above. What the skip directive is doing is causing the grammar not to care about leading whitespace in this rule, or whitespace around the `','` and `'='` in this rule.

More info here: http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/02/24/parsing-skippers-and-skipping-parsers/

---

Edit:

Also, I don't think the `skipped_t` is doing what you think it is there.

When you use a custom skipper, most straightforwardly you specify an actual instance of a parser as the skip parser for that rule. When you use a type instead of an object e.g. `qi::skip(qi::blank_type)`, that is a shorthand, where the tag-type `qi::blank_type` has been linked via prior template declarations to the type `qi::blank`, and qi knows that when it sees `qi::blank_type` in certain places that it should instantiate a `qi::blank` parser object.

I don't see any evidence that you've actually set up that machinery, you've just typedef'ed `skipped_t` to `token_type`. What you should do if you want this to work that way (if it's even possible, I don't know) is read about qi customization points and instead declare `qi::skipped_t` as an empty struct which is linked via some template boiler plate to the rule `m_comment`, which is presumably what you actually want to be skipping. (If you skip all tokens of all types, then you can't possibly match anything so that wouldn't make sense, so I'm not sure what your intention was with making `token_type` the skipper.)

My guess is that when `qi` saw that typedef `token_type` in your parameter list, that it either ignored it or interprets it as part of the return value of the rule or something like this, not sure exactly what it would do.

Comment: This sounds relly strange to me. I have some other code where I use qi alone (no lex) and skipper propagates to sub rules. That is why because of the qi::skip(...)[m_variable], the rule has to be declared with a skipper type: skipped_t

Comment: Note that on the page you mentioned, the skipper progagates through all the rules...

Comment: "note that on the page you mentioned the skipper propagates through all the rules..." no, it doesn't. here's hartmut's example, see it live on coliru. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd62add9e9ccb930 or, a variation using `skip` directive only: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5068a53556449c01

Comment: So I understand that in my simple example, what I should do is simply use skip in the m_variable rule (like in the commented part of my code). But in my real application (which is far more complex), is there a simple way to skip the comments everywhere by default and disable skipping using no_skip at some specific locations?

Comment: probably the ideal thing is to try add your skipper as a template parameter to all those rules, but I don't actually know how to do that, you might need to read about customization points or something. what I would probably do instead is, just write `skip(my_whitespace_rule) [` skip a line... <rule> `]` for every rule definition. and probably use a macro for the `skip(my_whitespace_rule)` part in case I want to change it en masse later. YMMV